# Intellij Idea is inserting space in each line and showing that whole file was modified in git pull request

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij adding a white space at starting of each line and causing for the Bitbucket git pull request showing as whole file was modified but the real code changes are only in two lines. Facing lot more problem with this, I have searched many but I did not get the correct solution.

Any help on this is much appreciated!!

[image: actual change]

[image: showingWholeFileChanged]

Thankyou,
Syamala.

Comment: What is the file type? Can you share the screenshot of the issue? What specific lines are changed? Is it due to file reformatting?

Comment: Thankyou for your respone @CrazyCoder. Please find the above links, acctualShanges and showingWholeFileChanged. I am working on java project. This issue is happening for java and xml files.  Thanks,syamala.

Comment: What does the diff in IntelliJ IDEA show? Could it be that the changes are in the line endings?

Comment: No. In intelli, while committing the changes through intelli the duff was showing with only my real changes. But while creating git pull request, facing this issue. Due to this reviewers cannot see the actual changes done by me.  in bitbucket pull request if we enable "ignoreWhiteSpaces" then the pull request showing only my changes(the first screenshot what I attached).  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may need to configure line endings according to your guidelines: https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings.

Comment: What is the solution for this?!